# Can't amend form.phtml as part of contact module magento 2

Tags: magento2, phtml

I'm trying to change copy in the `form.phtml` (**Magento_Contact module**) but whenever I upload the file to my theme, all I get back is this:

[image: Contact us error on page]

I've uploaded it to:
`app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml` along with the layout files (/layout)

The code is as follows:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<form class="form contact"
      action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
      echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
      id="contact-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
      echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Contact us') ?></span></legend>
        <br/>

        <div class="field note no-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget enim id nunc pulvinar rutrum non a massa. Morbi vulputate rhoncus eros tincidunt fermentum. Nulla velit purus, pulvinar et augue eget, elementum ultrices ligula. Vivamus at vehicula eros. ') ?></div>
        <div class="field name required">
            <label class="label" for="name"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo __('Name') ?></span></label>

            <div class="control">
                <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Name') ?>"
                       value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('name') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>"
                       class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo __('Email') ?></span></label>

            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Email') ?>"
                       value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('email') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>"
                       class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field telephone">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>

            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Phone Number') ?>"
                       value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('telephone')) ?>"
                       class="input-text" type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field comment required">
            <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?></span></label>

            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3"
                          data-validate="{required:true}"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('comment')) ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value=""/>
            <button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo __('Submit') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you have to remove layout file from your theme

Comment: I have removed the layout file but still get the same result